# Mysql PHP trouble updating a table from a list of results

Tags: php, mysql, loops, sql-update, multiple-tables

If anyone with patience can read this and help me, I would be overly grateful. I am having difficulty updating one mysql table. I have a table that stores dj's comments and feedback on record albums,and I have a second table that store the general info about the album. My problem is looping through each feedback row to UPDATE my table. I'm just going to post all of my code and perhaps it will be clearer (sorry for a lengthy post).

```
<?php

$done = false;
$problem = false;

$expected = array('album_id', 'dj','affilliations','rating','comments'
                  , 'content_id','title','ep','date','genre');

$conn = dbConnect('admin');

if ($_GET && !$_POST) {
  if (isset($_GET['album_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['album_id'])) {
    $album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
  }
  else {
    $album_id = NULL;
  }
  if ($album_id) {
    //this statement updates album_info correctly, but not album_comments
      $sql = "SELECT album_info.album_id, album_info.title, album_info.ep
               , album_info.genre, album_info.date, album_comments.content_id
               , album_comments.album_id, album_comments.dj
               , album_comments.affilliations, album_comments.rating
               , album_comments.comments 
             FROM album_info, album_comments 
             WHERE album_info.album_id = $album_id 
               AND album_comments.album_id = $album_id";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  }
}

// if form has been submitted, update record
if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) {
  // prepare expected items for insertion in to database
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $expected)) {
      ${$key} = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }
  }
  // abandon the process if primary key invalid
  if (!is_numeric($album_id)) {
    die('Invalid request');
  }
  if(!empty($_POST['dj']) && !empty($_POST['title'])) {
    $album_id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($album_id));
    $dj = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['dj']));
    $affilliations = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['affilliations']));
    $rating = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['rating']));
    $comments = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['comments']));
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['title']));
    $ep = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['ep']));
    $genre = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['genre']));
    $date = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['date']));

  }

  $sql="UPDATE album_info, album_comments 
       ON album_info.album_id = album_comments.album_id 
       SET album_info.title = '$title', album_info.ep = '$ep'
         , album_info.date = '$date', album_info.genre = '$genre'
         , album_comments.dj = '$dj'
         , album_comments.affilliations = '$affilliations'
         , album_comments.rating = '$rating'
         , album_comments.comments = '$comments' 
           album_comments.album_id = '$album_id' 
       AND album_info.album_id = '$album_id'";
    // submit the query and redirect if successful
  $done = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  if($done) {
    printf("<script>location.href='?page=albums'</script>");
  }
}
?>
```

This is correctly updating album_info, but album_comments needs to be looped through, as seen below:

```
<form id="album_form" name="album_form" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Album Info</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" 
        value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['title']); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ep">EP</label>
      <input type="text" name="ep" id="ep" 
        value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['ep']); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
     <label for="day">Date:</label>
      <input name="day" type="text id="day: size="2" maxlength="2" 
        value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['date']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="genre">Genre</label>
      <input type="text" name="genre" id="genre" 
        value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['genre']); ?>"/>
  </fieldset>
  </p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Comments</legend>
    <!--data below is from table album_comments -->
<table id="tblInsertRowPHP" class="tableResults" cellpadding="0" 
  cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
      <?php
      //this spits out all the feedback for the particular album; 
      //this is the part I need help with
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td>
          <?php

        echo '<input type="text" name="dj" size="15" value="'.$row['dj'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="affilliations" size="30"
              value="'.$row['affilliations'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="rating" size="8" 
              value="'.$row['rating'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="comments" size="68"
              value="'.$row['comments'].'" />';
          ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } 
        $sql = "SELECT album_id FROM album_info";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="update" 
     value="Update entry" id="submit" />
  <input name="album_id" type="hidden" 
     value="<?php echo $row['album_id']; ?>" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

How do amend the MYSQL statement to go through each row in album_comments and update them? Do I need a prepared statement, or can I change the PHP sql statement?? Thanks again for any help—I am somewhat new at this.

Comment: $sql="UPDATE album_info, album_comments 
       ON album_info.album_id = album_comments.album_id 
       SET album_info.title = '$title', album_info.ep = '$ep'
         , album_info.date = '$date', album_info.genre = '$genre'
         , album_comments.dj = '$dj'
         , album_comments.affilliations = '$affilliations'
         , album_comments.rating = '$rating'
         , album_comments.comments = '$comments' 
         `WHERE missing here`  album_comments.album_id = '$album_id' 
       AND album_info.album_id = '$album_id'";

Comment: You forgot a `WHERE` in your update statement, see comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your `album_comment` table has a `comment_id` primary key (integer, auto increment, like `album_info.album_id` I guess), you could try the following:

```
<?php

$done = false;
$problem = false;

$expected = array('album_id', 'dj','affilliations','rating','comments', 'content_id','title','ep','date','genre');

$conn = dbConnect('admin');

if ($_GET && !$_POST) {
    if (isset($_GET['album_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['album_id'])) {
        $album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
    }
    else {
        $album_id = NULL;
    }
    if ($album_id) {
    //this statement updates album_info correctly, but not album_comments
        $sql = "SELECT album_info.album_id, album_info.title, album_info.ep, album_info.genre, album_info.date, album_comments.content_id, album_comments.album_id, album_comments.dj, album_comments.affilliations, album_comments.rating, album_comments.comments FROM album_info, album_comments WHERE album_info.album_id = $album_id AND album_comments.album_id = $album_id";

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
}

// if form has been submitted, update record
if (array_key_exists('update', $_POST)) {
    // prepare expected items for insertion in to database
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $expected)) {
            ${$key} = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        }
    }
    // abandon the process if primary key invalid
    if (!is_numeric($album_id)) {
        die('Invalid request');
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['dj']) && !empty($_POST['title'])) {
        $album_id = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($album_id));
        $title = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['title']));
        $ep = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['ep']));
        $genre = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['genre']));
        $date = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['date']));

    }

    $sql="UPDATE album_info SET title = '$title', ep = '$ep', date = '$date', genre = '$genre' WHERE album_id = '$album_id'";

    $done = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach($_POST['comment_id'] as $index => $comment_id)
    {
        $comment_id = intval($comment_id);
        $dj = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['dj'][$index]));
        $affilliations = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['affilliations'][$index]));
        $rating = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['rating'][$index]));
        $comments = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['comments'][$index]));

        $sql="UPDATE album_comments SET dj = '$dj', affilliations = '$affilliations', rating = '$rating', comments = '$comments' WHERE comment_id = '$comment_id'";

        $done = $done && mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    // submit the query and redirect if successful
    if($done) {
        printf("<script>location.href='?page=albums'</script>");
    }
}
?>
```

Second part:

```
    <form id="album_form" name="album_form" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Album Info</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['title']); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ep">EP</label>
      <input type="text" name="ep" id="ep" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['ep']); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
     <label for="day">Date:</label>
      <input name="day" type="text id="day: size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['date']); ?>"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="genre">Genre</label>
      <input type="text" name="genre" id="genre" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row['genre']); ?>"/>
  </fieldset>
  </p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Comments</legend>
    <!--data below is from table album_comments -->
<table id="tblInsertRowPHP" class="tableResults" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
      <?php
      //this spits out all the feedback for the particular album; this is the part I need help with
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      ?>
      <tr>
          <td>
          <?php
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id[]" value="'.$row['comment_id'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="dj[]" size="15" value="'.$row['dj'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="affilliations[]" size="30" value="'.$row['affilliations'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="rating[]" size="8" value="'.$row['rating'].'" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="comments[]" size="68" value="'.$row['comments'].'" />';
          ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } 
        $sql = "SELECT album_id FROM album_info";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update entry" id="submit" />
  <input name="album_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['album_id']; ?>" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```